# How can I pass dynamic value to href property in table created with vue,js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Dobry den, everybody!
I have a daynamic table, created with vue.js

```
<tbody>
   <tr v-for="(row, index) in tableData">
     <td>{{ (index + 1)  }}</td>
     <td>{{ row.link }}</td>
     <td>{{ row.location}}</td>
     <td class="small center">{{ row.useful }}</td>
     <td class="small center">{{ row.useless }}</td>
     <td class="small center">{{ row.neverResponded }}</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Now I want to make a link clickable but don`t know how to do it. Here is what I tried:

```
 <tbody>
   <tr v-for="(row, index) in tableData">
     <td>{{ (index + 1)  }}</td>
     <td><a href="{{ row.link }}">{{ row.link }}</a></td>
     <td>{{ row.location}}</td>
     <td class="small center">{{ row.useful }}</td>
     <td class="small center">{{ row.useless }}</td>
     <td class="small center">{{ row.neverResponded }}</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

But value is not passed because of quotes (obviously). Is there any way to pass this variable to href? Thank you!

Comment: <td> <a :hrf="row.link" </a></td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind your link:

```
<td><a :href="row.link">{{ row.link }}</a></td>
```